# Error generating chart: The image collection is empty

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-explorer

```
// Define a geometry.
var geometry = ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(
  [[[[-113.04179687499999, 42.7991879605782],
     [-113.04179687499999, 41.56178373305603],
     [-110.75664062499999, 41.56178373305603],
     [-110.75664062499999, 42.7991879605782]]],
   [[[-111.45976562499999, 41.955158501392994],
     [-111.45976562499999, 40.96720543432847],
     [-109.87773437499999, 40.96720543432847],
     [-109.87773437499999, 41.955158501392994]]]], null, false);

// Make the geometry a feature collection.
var Samarkand = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry);

// Import S2 image collection.
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  // Filter collection.
  .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-10-01')
  .filterBounds(Samarkand)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20);

// Define a cloud masking function.
var maskcloud1 = function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

// Define an index function (return only MSAVI).
var MSAVI = function(image) {
  return image.expression(
    '(2 * NIR + 1 - sqrt(pow((2 * NIR + 1), 2) - 8 * (NIR - RED)) ) / 2', 
    {
      'NIR': image.select('B8'), 
      'RED': image.select('B4'), 
    }).rename('MSAVI').copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
};

// Apply the cloud mask function.
var MSAVIcol = S2.map(maskcloud1)
 // Apply the MSAVI transformation.
 .map(MSAVI);

// Calculate the per-pixel median MSAVI for all images in collection.
var MSAVImed = MSAVIcol.median();

// Define vis params.
var MSAVIvis = {
  palette: ['#d73027', '#f46d43', '#fdae61', '#fee08b', '#d9ef8b', '#a6d96a'],
  min: -0.5,
  max: 0.9};

// Plot a time series of 
var plotMSAVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:MSAVIcol,
  regions: Samarkand,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start',
  seriesProperty: 'system:index'})
  .setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
    title: 'MSAVI Samarkand 2018',
    hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
    vAxis: {title: 'MSAVI'},
});

// Display the results.
print(plotMSAVI);
Map.addLayer(MSAVImed.clipToCollection(Samarkand), MSAVIvis, 'MSAVI');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have images in your collection. That is because you filter Landsat imagery on the 'CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE' property, which is only present in Sentinel. The correct Landsat property name is 'CLOUD_COVER'.

```
// Import S2 image collection.
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  // Filter collection.
  .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-10-01')
  .filterBounds(Samarkand)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 20);

print(S2)
```